# Having the output printed on the screen and redirected to a file and forwarded the errors to another file

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel, io-redirection, tee

I’m trying to answer this lab question. Is there a way to solve this without using `tee` command?

As user1 on server1, run the `ls` command on `/etc`, `/dvd`, and `/var`. Have the output printed on the screen as well as redirected to file `/tmp/ioutput`, and the errors forwarded to file `/tmp/ioerror`. Check both files after the execution of the command and analyze the results. (Hint: Input, Output, and Error Redirections).

If I tried like this, the output is not printed on the screen.

```
[user1@server1 ~]$ ls /etc /dvd /var 1> /tmp/ioutput 2> /tmp/ioerror
```

If I used with `tee` command, error file was empty.

```
ls /etc /dvd /var | tee /tmp/ioutput 2> /tmp/ioerror
```

Is there a way to solve it only by using redirection operators?

Comment: @Quasimodo, Thanks for your clarification. However, I think it should be in a single command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `tee`. But to get the standard error output, you need to redirect the standard error of the original program. The pipe (`|`) is only passing the standard output to `tee`, that's why the error file is empty. What you wanted is:

```
ls /etc /dvd /var 2> /tmp/ioerror | tee /tmp/ioutput
```

If you want to see both stderr and stdout on screen, try this:

```
ls /etc /dvd /var 2> >(tee /tmp/ioerror) | tee /tmp/ioutput
```

That will first redirect stderr to `tee /tmp/ioerror`, which means you will both see it on screen and have it in the file, and then it pipes the stdout to `tee /tmp/ioutput`  ensuring that too is both printed and saved to the file.

Comment: thanks for your kind and quick support. 

Yes, your first method is ok to write in both files and also display the output only on the screen. It’ll be enough for my lab answer.

Then, if I tried to see both on screen, the error file was still empty.

Comment: @Tun sorry, I was missing an extra `>`, try the updated answer.

Comment: arr, yes, it's ok now. thanks again for ur updated answer.